# showcolorimage function only display image only in red channel

Tags: scilab

I am new with SciLab

I am using SciLab 5.5.0-beta-1

```
r=ReadImage('2.jpg'); // loads successfully
ShowColorImage(r,''); // here is the problem
```

I got only red channel output, 
not getting original RGB color image

please help how to fix this problem

thank you

Comment: What toolbox are you using for image processing?

Comment: installed though module manager SVP and SIVP

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in SIVP would be:

```
my_image = imread('2.jpg');
imshow( my_image );
```

See documentation of SIVP functions [here](http://sivp.sourceforge.net/func-list-0.5.0/whatis.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, when I up(?)graded to Scilab 5.5.0. But my code works perfectly with Scilab 5.4.1 where it was developed originally, so I recommend to you to use the previous version of Scilab until this bug is fixed.